# How to get portlet id from it's configuration portlet?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

How can I get portlet id in jsp page of it's configuration portlet?

From the level of specific portlet I can call in .jsp page:

```
String portletId = themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getId();
```

How can I get that id in configuration portlet's jsp?

Comment: I think you can try portletSession to store that id..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly this should give you portletId

```
final String portletResource = ParamUtil.getString(request, "portletResource");

final String portletId = PortletConstants.getRootPortletId(portletResource);
```

Answer (score 0):

hello you can try this :

```
String portletId = themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getId();
String portletName = themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getPortletName();
String portletInstanceId = themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getInstanceId();
```

Don't forget:

```
<% ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    themeDisplay.getUser().getScreenName(); %>
```